# KDE Neon Bluetooth Audio not working

Tags: audio, bluetooth, kde-neon

I have a Gateway GWTN156-12RD running on KDE Neon, an Ubuntu 22.04-based distro. And ever since I got the OS, the bluetooth audio NEVER works. No matter how many times or how hard I try, there is no way I can get *any* bluetooth audio device to show up in the audio settings. I have tried editing every bluetooth-related config file possible and nothing registers. Help? 
My device does support bluetooth since the mouse connects and works just fine. My main problem is when an audio device connects that all this happens.
Help?

Sincerely,
Saturanium